# Why does my code returns this error: java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Persona persona1 = new Persona();
        try{
            StringTokenizer st;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("entrada.txt"));
            String linea = br.readLine();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("datos.csv"));

            while(linea != null){
                st = new StringTokenizer(linea);
                persona1.setNombre(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setRFC(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setSueldoMensual(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setPrimaVacacional(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setGastosHospitalarios(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setGastosFunerarios(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setSGMM(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setGastosHipotecarios(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setDonativos(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setAportacionRetiro(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setTransporteEscolar(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setNivelEducativo(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setColegiaturaTotal(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));

                pw.println(persona1.getNombre() + "," + persona1.getRFC() + "," + persona1.getSueldoMensual()
            + "," + persona1.getPrimaVacacional() + "," + persona1.getGastosHospitalarios() + "," + persona1.getGastosFunerarios()
            + "," + persona1.getSGMM() + "," + persona1.getGastosHipotecarios() + "," + persona1.getDonativos()
            + "," + persona1.getAportacionRetiro() + "," + persona1.getTransporteEscolar()
            + "," + persona1.getNivelEducativo() + "," + persona1.getColegiaturaTotal());
            }
            br.close();
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error " + ex);
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My program receives a .txt file and returns the information in a .csv file but when I run it it returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

This doesn´t make sense because I have another program that does a similar thing but I cant figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Because the line doesn't have a next token when you try to get it at line 26 of your class. Rea the documentation of StringTokenizer. Check your input file.

Comment: It didn't return this error, it threw this exception. Correct terminology please.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there is no token and you try to set it and the exception says there is no such element.

In order to avoid NoSuchElementException, you should always check whether there is more tokens with the help of [StringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#hasMoreTokens%28%29) .

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
         //do things
     }
```

My thinking is that a String ends up as an empty String ("") when the tokenizer is done, not null.